# MySQL - Converting from VARCHAR to INT truncates data - why?

Tags: mysql, types

I have a database of several million phone numbers of customer records. 
The phone number column is currently a VARCHAR(30). I believe this is slowing down large queries. All phone numbers are only 10 digits so I tried to convert to a INT(10). This dramatically increased performance but then I noticed it truncated a lot of the numbers to all be the same.

Why?

What should I do to get my INT(10) and resolve this?

Comment: A phone number is not a real number, store them as strings. PS: `int(10)` doesn't mean it will hold 10 digits, signed int is of `2^32 - 1` capacity for positive numbers

Comment: Can you give examples of the numbers that it truncated to be the same?

Comment: Choose the datatype which fits best to your requirements. Performance issues should be addressed with indexes and reasonable queries (given a reasonable scheme).